# What's wrong with this attempt to use SimpleXML?

Tags: php, simplexml

I can't seem to get anything to work with simpleXML for PHP. What is wrong with the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<book><title>The Title</title></book>');
$title = $xml->book->title;
echo "<pre>title = $title\n</pre>";
```

The resulting output is:

```
title =
```

Why isn't the output as follows?

```
title = The Title
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `<book>` is the root node of this snippet, you need `$xml->title` rather than  `$xml->book->title`.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string('<book><title>The Title</title></book>');
$title = $xml->title;
echo "<pre>title = $title\n</pre>";

// Prints
<pre>title = The Title
</pre>
```

The structure is more easily discovered if you `var_dump()` it:

```
var_dump($xml);
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (1) {
  ["title"]=>
  string(9) "The Title"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
$str = '<book><title>The Title</title></book>';
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($str);

$title = $xml->book->title;

echo $title;
```

What I suspect the problem being is that you haven't created the XML object and are trying to use a method from that object. Thats my assumption given your code snippet.

Take a look at [PHP: Simple XML](http://us.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)